# File Upload Path in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am a spring beginner, I am developing an application in which I am giving user option to upload Images using Apache Commons File Upload.

I am having confusion on what should be the file upload path, My development environment is windows and application will be deployed on Linux environment.

If I do not specify the path, Files are uploaded to the eclipse installation directory

```
String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream();
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
```

I read somewhere to specify path of java.io.tmpdir in which case it is C:\Users\Tushar\AppData\Local\Temp\ for Windows

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

What should be the correct approach for specifying the path such that it works on both windows and linux, in a way that I should directly be able to use the path in image tag in my jsp's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I've usually done this is to configure a path in some properties file such as

```
upload.path=/opt/company/uploads
```

On linux, the path is normal. On Windows, it will be converted to `C:/opt/company/uploads`, where `C:` is your drive.

You can then build `fileName` from the `upload.path` property value. Use the `File` or `Path` api

```
File file = new File("/opt/stuff/uploads", multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
Path path = Paths.get("/opt/stuff/uploads", multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
```

as long as `multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()` returns just the file name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, when I try this I get the following exception    java.io.FileNotFoundException: \opt\stuff\uploads\chroniclecat100.png (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: @tushar try creating the directory first.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I am not able to display the image on jsp page. I opened a separate question for that, would be great if you can help me with that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888648/access-files-that-are-outside-webapp-tomcat-v6-and-spring

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Tushar can you use properties file or set path to `/your/path/filesystem/` everywhere on **UNIX** or **WIN**. Can you try something like that onto .properties:

```
#PATH
yourvariable=/your/path/filesystem/
```

And from java source code can you read .properties file

This can does allocate everywhere system enviroment.

**I hope help you :)**

Answer (score 0):

All os include unix and win , has user home folder ,and It is better to specify a path for your app inside home folder,store directly inside C: and opt may cause accessibility problem later. use:

```
        String userHome = System.getProperty( "user.home" );
```

and specify subfolder for your app started from home may be best choice.

Answer (score 0):

application.properties

```
upload.path =/C:/your/path
```

MvcConfig

```
@Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("file://" + uploadPath + "/");
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        }
```