# Access files that are outside webapp (Tomcat V6 and Spring)

Tags: spring, tomcat

I am giving option to upload images and the Images are being upload to opt/uploads/contactImages which in the case of windows is C:/opt/uploads/contactImages

I want to display Images in my JSP. For which I tried to configure my tomcat by adding the following tag under Host tag.

```
<Context docBase="/opt/uploads/contactImages/" path="/images" />
```

But when I try to access

```
http://localhost:8080/images/file.png
```

I get 404 Error. Where I am going wrong?

Update

Servlet web.xml file

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: I don't Tomcat can't just serve up files like this. Do you have a servlet web.xml descriptor we can see?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have added web.xml in the question

Comment: And do you have a `<mvc:resources>` or other handler for your images?

Comment: Yes I have the `<mvc:resource>` tag   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />  , I think this tag is to access the resources which are in webapp and not outside the app

Comment: try putting it in /opt/uploads/contactImages/resources/file.png and access http://localhost:8080/images/resources/file.png, that *should* work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Servlet` or a resource handler can't just serve files from the file system directly. You need to write your own `@Controller` handler methods. For example

```
@Controller
public class ImagesController {

    public static final String BASE_PATH = "/opt/uploads/contactImages";

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{fileName}" , method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> getFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
        FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource(new File(BASE_PATH, fileName));
        ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(resource, HttpStatus.OK);
        return responseEntity;
    }
}
```

With the [`ResponseEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) class you can also set different response headers and status codes.

You can now access the above at

```
http://localhost:8080/images/file.png
```

I don't think the above will work for files in nested directories.

---

Note that the `docBase` attribute in

```
<Context docBase="/opt/uploads/contactImages/" path="/images" />
```

is incorrect. The [`docBase`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html) attribute specifies

> The Document Base (also known as the Context Root) directory for this
>   web application, or the pathname to the web application archive file
>   (if this web application is being executed directly from the WAR
>   file). You may specify an absolute pathname for this directory or WAR
>   file, or a pathname that is relative to the appBase directory of the
>   owning Host.

So it has to point to your web application, not a random directory where you store files.

Comment: the code returns xml, strange. The file is outside the webapp in `e:` directory if that helps.

Comment: The controller in the code returned xml/json, on checking I found there were 3 messageConverters registered, two of jackson and one string converter. Which conveter is required to actually download the file ? Tried ByteArray and Resource but now I get files of size 0 bytes downloaded.

Comment: @coding_idiot You need a `ResourceHttpMessageConverter` to properly serialize a `Resource`. Consider asking a new question if that isn't working for you.

Comment: thanks it worked. For others `produces="application/octet-stream"` is must for `@RequestMapping`.